# NASM Linux 32-bit: scanf, printf calls

Tags: linux, assembly, printf, nasm, scanf

I've written simple assembly code, which uses `printf` and `scanf` to write and read numbers, to and from command line respectively.For this particular code, I'm getting output different from given input. It seems that first value printed is `[var1]+[var2]*2^8` . However, by increasing size of variables `var1` & `var2` to 4 bytes, code gives correct output. How?

```
    ;assemble and compile with :
    ;nasm -f elf testing.asm && gcc -m32 -o testing testing.o
    extern printf,scanf

    ;store eax,ebc,ecx,edx onto the stack
    %macro push_reg 0
    push edx
    push ecx
    push ebx
    push eax
    %endmacro

    ;restore eax,ebx,ecx,edx
    %macro pop_reg 0
    pop eax
    pop ebx
    pop ecx
    pop edx
    %endmacro

    section .text
    global main
    main:
    ;reads number var1
    push_reg          
    push var1
    push formatin
    call scanf          ;scanf("%d",var1);
    add esp,8           ;restoring stack pointer 
    pop_reg            

    ;reads number var1
    push_reg
    push var2
    push formatin
    call scanf        ;scanf("%d",var2);
    add esp,8         ;restoring stack pointer 
    pop_reg           

    ;printing number var1
    push_reg          
    push dword[var1]
    push formatout
    call printf       ;printf("%d",content of var1);
    add esp,8         ;restoring stack pointer 
    pop_reg          

    ;printing number var2
    push_reg
    push dword[var2]
    push formatout
    call printf       ;printf("%d",content of var2);
    add esp,8         ;restoring stack pointer 
    pop_reg       

    exit:
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80

    section .bss
    var1 resb 1
    var2 resb 1

    section .data
    formatout: db "%d",10,0
    formatin: db "%d",0
```

Input:

```
1
1
```

Output:

```
257
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You told `scanf` & `printf` you were scanning/printing integers, which are typically 32-bit (or 4-byte) values.  So they behaved as if they were, using that much data at the addresses you provided.

Comment: While pushing content of `var1` & `var2` on stack as parameters of printf, they're passed as dword. So, they are 32-bits numbers each. Right?

Comment: @user148865 I'm pretty sure you declared them as just one byte each.  You should change your declaration so they're 4 bytes each.

Comment: @1.618:Yes, I mentioned in question that by making each of variables as 4 byte each, it works correctly. Why is it not working when they're of 1 byte? I'm passing each one in in an argument as dword. So, 4 byte word. Right?

Comment: @user148865 Think about what would happen in c if you did this: `char a = 10; printf("%d", *(int*)&a);`

Comment: Yes, your passing them as a DWORD to the functions.   Your passing the address of the variable, which us DWORD sized.  The memory pointed to by the address your passing is only 1 byte.

Comment: Thanks. I see what is happening: As printf will take the input of 4 bytes and `var1` is of 1 byte, input will be `[3-bytes after var1][var1]`.